# how to add a SharePoint custom group to just 1 specific custom list

Tags: list, permissions, custom-list, inheritance

Is there is a way to add a custom SharePoint group to a custom list in SharePoint 2013 and be available to only that list and not to any other lists on the site.

I tried adding a group to a list and went to all other lists on the break the inheritance and removed the group i don't want from the lists but when i add a new group on the site i cannot add that new group to other lists in the site. If i change to inherit from the parent permission i am getting the group which i don't want to the list as well.

Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Breaking permissions inheritance is terrible practice and should be done sparingly. You're setting yourself up for a serious headache later on.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a group to see only one list, or list to be available to only one group? Either way there's no need to break role inheritance on all lists.

SharePoint groups are created on site collection level, you cannot add a group only for a list.

What you need to do is:

- Create new group without assigning any permissions on site level
- Break role inheritance only for this one specific list
- Add appropriate permission level for new group on the list (and remove other permissions if required)
- SharePoint will automatically assign *Limited access* right to parent objects (it's required to login to the site)

Permissions in SharePoint are either unique or inherited. If you break role inheritance and assign permisions on parent level, they won't be pushed down.